# Unable to remove rows/cell values in Excel; extra lines are shown in TXT after being saved as CSV File

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-csv

I am writing a code to convert the data from an Excel file to a CSV file. But before converting into a CSV file, I want to run over the data to remove any empty rows. After converting, the code will be opened in Notepad for users to view. I realized that as long as there are formatting in any of the cells, it will be seen as a blank cell.

In the screenshot shown below, I changed the formats of the 3 lines (row 14, 15 and 16). [After adding and deleting of the rows, these are blank fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08xJT.png)

After the conversion, I then realized that there are 3 extra lines which just looks like ",,,,,". [Extra 3 lines at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpLfP.png)

I tried to remove the formats, but formats such as fonts cannot be removed. The only way I can go about doing this is to delete the extra blank rows with format.

In my VBA code below, I managed to detect columns with fields that contains blank spaces, but I can't seem to delete the rows. I have thought it was a format issue and used .ClearFormats and .ClearContents, but they do not work either. I am not sure how else can I remove these rows.

However, I am positive that any form of format change in any cell will cause the extra lines. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

My Current Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCSV()

'Declare the data type of the variables
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim sFilename As String
Dim cellValue As String
Dim MyTextFile
'Dim previous As Dataset

'Set the Wkb to the current active workbook and set Wks to the current sheet opened
Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Set the location of the csv file to a variable
sFilename = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\cp_resi_nostro.csv"

'Set the column and row number of last cell that is not empty to a variable
lastCol = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
lastRow = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Check through each cell to identify any empty cells
For iRow = 1 To lastRow
    For iCol = 1 To lastCol
        cellValue = wks.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value

    Next iCol

    'If Trim(cellValue) = "" Then
        'Rows(iRow).Delete
        'wks.AcceptChanges()
    'End If
Next iRow

'Save as .CSV file and in a specific folder stated
wks.SaveAs Filename:=sFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Notify users that the .CSV file has been saved
MsgBox sFilename & " saved"

'To ask Ash which format he wants
MyTextFile = Shell("C:\Windows\notepad.exe C:\Users\Public\Desktop\cp_resi_nostro.csv", vbNormalFocus)

'Set Wkb and Wks to its default value
Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace everything here,

```
'Set the column and row number of last cell that is not empty to a variable
lastCol = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
lastRow = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Check through each cell to identify any empty cells
For iRow = 1 To lastRow
    For iCol = 1 To lastCol
        cellValue = wks.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value

    Next iCol

    'If Trim(cellValue) = "" Then
        'Rows(iRow).Delete
        'wks.AcceptChanges()
    'End If
Next iRow
```

... with,

```
with wks
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        lastCol = .columns.count
        lastRow = .rows.count
    end with
    .cells(lastRow + 1, 1).resize(rows.count - lastRow, 1).entirerow.CLEAR
    .cells(1, lastCol + 1).resize(1, columns.count - lastCol).entirecolumn.CLEAR
    .usedrange
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        for lastCol = 1 to .columns.count
            .columns(lastCol).cells = .columns(lastCol).cells.value2
        next lastCol
    end with
end with
```

The [Range.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223824%28v=office.11%29.aspx) should completely clear the cell of any residual properties and calling the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) resets itself.

Comment: Hi, sorry to trouble you again. If I also want to remove any blank spaces in the remaining rows, how do I go about inserting `TRIM` into the code you have provided?

Comment: I've changed the code above to reduce cells containing zero-length strings (aka `""` ) to truly blank cells. If this is insufficient, I would humbly suggest starting a new question with the revised code and more detail as to what the issue at hand is.